# why does not pyfirmata import?

Tags: python, arduino, pyfirmata

I just wanted to make python and Arduino work together. I saw tutorial that showed that we need library called "Pyfirmata" to do it.  when I type "pip install pyfirmata" in command prompt, it shows that the library is already installed. but when I type "import pyfirmata" in python it shows error that library does not exist. please help me if you can.

when I type "pip install pyfirmata" in command prompt, it shows that the library is already installed. but when I type "import pyfirmata" in python it shows error that library does not exist. please help me if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me, check if your ide is using the same version of python you installed Pyfirmata with

Comment: oh my god thank you so much it was installed in 3.10.6 and i was using 3.10.4 version. thank you I really appreciate that